# Hazelcast 3.8-EA WARNING:Received data format is invalid issue

Tags: java, hazelcast

while loading Map from external data source using MapLoader Hazelcast cluster(multicast discovery) gives error as

```
    WARNING: [<IP>]:5702 [<cluster_name>] [3.8-EA] Received data format is invalid. (An old version of Hazelcast may be running here.)
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Problem while reading DataSerializable, namespace: 0, id: 0, class: 'com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.JoinRequest', exception: com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.JoinRequest
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.rethrowReadException(DataSerializableSerializer.java:178)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.JoinRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

I have tested this on hazelast 3.5.4 version .. It is working fine.
We can ignore this warning but not sure what is the impact of it. Also it floods the log.

Comment: Is an old cluster still running and using multicast to discover with the same multicast group?

Comment: That i am not sure , but we have given unique name                          <group>
    <name>unique_name</name>
    <password>password</password>
</group>                                                                                                   will this guarantee unique cluster and other cluster dose not interfere into this?

Comment: Problem is, that the multicast discovery data protocol changed heavily between those versions, so the 3.8-EA most probably cannot read it anymore. Please configure a different multicast group: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8-EA/manual/html-single/index.html#multicast-element

Comment: After changing group multicast-group or multicast-port it is working fine. Thanks. Can you please update the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old and new versions of Hazelcast are not compatible in terms of multicast discovery since the internal protocol changed. That said, the new Hazelcast version cannot identify the old versions discovery packet.

Please change the multicast group according to the documentation found under: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8-EA/manual/html-single/index.html#multicast-element

Answer (score -1):

For those that may be running into this problem in an OSGi environment, you may be getting bit by a nuance of the com.hazelcast.util.ServiceLoader.findHighestReachableClassLoader() method sometimes picking the wrong class loader during Hazelcast initialization (as it won't always pick the class loader you set on the config).  The following shows a way to work around that problem by taking advantage of Java's context class loader:

```
private HazelcastInstance createHazelcastInstance() {  

    // Use the following if you're only using the Hazelcast data serializers   
    final ClassLoader classLoader = Hazelcast.class.getClassLoader();

    // Use the following if you have custom data serializers that you need
    // final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    final com.hazelcast.config.Config config = new com.hazelcast.config.Config();
    config.setClassLoader(classLoader);
    final ClassLoader previousContextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    } finally {
        if(previousContextClassLoader != null) {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(previousContextClassLoader);
        }
    }
}
```